# flask/jinja2: form textinput set value

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

How do I set the `VALUE` attribut of a text input field (HTML forms).

I tried it with:

Python:

```
@app.route("/function_a", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def function_a():
    form = ReusableForm(request.form)
    query = "test value"
    if request.method == 'POST':
    name=request.form['name']
    return render_template('zeit.html', form=form, query_test=query)
```

HTML template:

```
{{ form.name(value="{{ query_test }}") }}
```

the website output is like:

```
<input id="name" name="name" required type="text" value="{{query_test}}">
```

expected website output:

```
<input id="name" name="name" required type="text" value="test value">
```

Comment: `ReusableForm` is a class so instead of setting the value in the template do it in python code. `form.name="test value"`

Comment: It is still the same output without a value.

Comment: In the template delete setting value, make sure you have only `{{ form.name }}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution:

in the HTML template I wrote only the variable without the brackets.

```
{{ form.name(value=query_test) }}
```

and the output is like I want it:

```
<input id="name" name="name" required type="text" value="test value">
```